# Android gradle package R does not exist in heir library

Tags: android, gradle, android-resources, android-gradle-plugin

I am not able to use resourse "net.londatiga.android.R.drawable.menu_down_arrow" file from "NewQuickAction3D" library in heir library called "AndroidXXXLib", but other classes I am able to use.

**I get an error during gradle build "error: package net.londatiga.android.R does not exist".**
**How can I fix build scripts to have ability of use "net.londatiga.android.R" in my heir library?**

***The main goal is be able to use android resources from parent library inside heir library.***

There are dependencies between projects:

- AndroidXXXDemo

  - AndroidXXXLib

    - DragSortListView
    - NewQuickAction3D

**settings.gradle** file in root folder contains:

```
include ':libraries:DragSortListView:DragSortListViewLib'
include ':libraries:NewQuickAction3D:NewQuickAction3DLib'
include ':AndroidXXXLib'
include ':AndroidXXXDemo'
```

It is **build.gradle** inside **AndroidXXXLib**:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'
apply plugin: 'idea'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {

    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':libraries:DragSortListView:DragSortListViewLib')
    compile project(':libraries:NewQuickAction3D:NewQuickAction3DLib')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+'
    compile 'net.simonvt.menudrawer:menudrawer:3.0.+@aar'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
}
```

idea project looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Issue resolved.

**Build tool merge all resources, that's why main R file of my heir library has to be used instead of  "net.londatiga.android.R".**

Note: Also need to make sure that there are no identical layout names in projects resources to avoid errors related to missing view ids ([Priority Order for Library Dependencies](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-merging))